# Size Of Input Assumption in DAA

Tags: algorithm, time

During analysis of algorithms, why we often make the assumption that the size of the input n
is an exact power of an integer such as 2, i.e. n=2^k for some k ≥ 0
We say that this is a safe assumption for asymptotic analysis, but why? Why does it not
affect our analysis? After all, in practical scenarios n will mostly not be an exact power?

Comment: @ali - can you give us some example? What does mean "we" - like your teacher? What is DAA?

Comment: Typically (but there are exceptions) the effort changes smoothly with `n` so it will not be the case that it is for example high at the points n=2^k and low in between.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of [Why can we assume that for T(n) = 2T(n/2) + theta(1), n is a power of 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30995094/why-can-we-assume-that-for-tn-2tn-2-theta1-n-is-a-power-of-2).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can we assume that for T(n) = 2T(n/2) + theta(1), n is a power of 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30995094/why-can-we-assume-that-for-tn-2tn-2-theta1-n-is-a-power-of-2)